# Factorise an expression according to a function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression like this on mathematica :

```
A=9/4 SixJ0[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] (-36 SixJ0[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
     0] (SixJ0[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] - SixJ1[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]) SixJ1[1, 
     0, 1, 0, 1, 0] + 
   SixJ0[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
     0]^2 (5 SixJ0[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] + 
      12 (-SixJ1[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] + SixJ2[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])) + 
   36 SixJ0[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
     1] (SixJ1[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]^2 + 
      SixJ0[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] SixJ2[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]))
```

SIXJ2 is a function taking 6 parameters. What I want to do is to factorise by the SIXJ2. Thus, I want that mathematica writes me something like :

```
A=(smth1*SixJ2[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]+smth2*SixJ2[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

But I don't know by advance what will be the parameters of my SixJ2 function, I want it automatically see how many different SIXJ2[parameters] I have, factorise by each of them.

An info maybe usefull : my expression sn linear on the SIXJ2, so I will never have SIXJ2[a,b,c,d,e,f]*SIXJ2[x,y,z,u,v,h] for example.

Comment: Do you know in advance that the parameters to your function will be 1 or 0?

Comment: No I don't, I can have any parameters (and here it was 1 or 0 but in fact it can be any integers or half integers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Collect` different `SixJ2` symbols directly:

```
Collect[Expand[A], _SixJ2, Simplify]
```

But if you just want to know how many different `SixJ2` symbols you have, you can use `Cases`:

```
Union@Cases[A, _SixJ2, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {SixJ2[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], SixJ2[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have seen the notation function[ ___ ]but I didn't understood what it meant. I understand that it will solve my problem but what exactly does function[ ___ ] mean ? I would be grateful for some explanation. Thanks !!

Comment: `function[___]` is pattern which means `function` with any arguments. You can look in the documentation for `BlankNullSequence` and other patterns.

Comment: I prefer using the pattern `_SixJ2` instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll I agree, `_SixJ2` is a more elegant pattern. I have updated the answer.